# How to detect Windows Phone device using "software navigation bar"?

Tags: windows-phone-8, navigationbar

On some new Windows Phone devices, the navigation bar (with 3 buttons: back, home, search) will be contained on screen, instead 3 hardware buttons at the bottom of the device (old version).

How can I detect a device using software or hardware navigation bar (C#)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's still not in the [API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207212%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for `Windows Phone 8`, and even it has not been updated for `Windows Phone 8.1` too since the release.

[Windows Phone 8.1 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197881/)